# WPF DataTrigger never fires to Expand TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML which should expand my whole treeview when a specific property ExpandNodes is True, but it is never triggered.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExpandNodes}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExpandNodes}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

// some other code

</TreeView>
```

In my ViewModel I set ExpandNodes to True during a specific event, yet the treeview remains non expanded. It's not an issue with my DataContext as I have other properties from the same Viewmodel that are bound and work fine.

My Viewmodel:

```
private bool _expandnodes;
public bool ExpandNodes
{
    get
    {
        return _expandnodes;
    }
    set
    {
        _expandnodes = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ExpandNodes");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string PropName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));
    }
}
```

Comment: And there is a property change notification when the ExpandNodes value changes?

Comment: Yes, see my edits above for part of my Viewmodel

Comment: In case there is a single ExpandNodes property at the same level as the ItemsSource collection, try `{Binding DataContext.ExpandNodes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Too compliacted, you can simply bind `IsExpanded` property to your object and raise PropertyChanged event.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
           <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding ExpandNodes, 
            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
            TargetNullValue=False}" />
         </Style>
     </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
// some other code
</TreeView>
```